# How do I manipulate a distance object in r to extract just the values I want?

Tags: r, vegan

I'm trying to conduct an analysis where I need to know the relative change in community composition over time using Sørensen's or bray-Curtis distance.  I have a matrix of plots that looks like this:

```
> example
plot species_a species_b species_c
1    1      0.16      0.25      0.00
2    2      0.00      1.00      0.00
3    3      0.70      0.00      0.25
4    1      1.00      0.00      0.00
5    2      0.10      0.40      0.50
6    3      0.30      0.30      0.30
7    1      0.20      0.20      0.60
8    2      0.11      0.12      0.13
9    3      0.00      0.00      0.90
```

In this example data I have 3 plots, measured at 3 different points in time, in my real data I have 850 plots measured at 3 different points in time.
I can easily calculate a distance matrix using r and the vegan package function vegdist:

```
 example<-example[,-1]
 di<-vegdist(example, method="bray")
          1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8
2 0.6453901                                                                      
3 0.7647059 1.0000000                                                            
4 0.7730496 1.0000000 0.2820513                                                  
5 0.5035461 0.6000000 0.6410256 0.9000000                                        
6 0.3740458 0.6842105 0.4054054 0.6842105 0.2631579                              
7 0.4893617 0.8000000 0.5384615 0.8000000 0.2000000 0.2631579                    
8 0.4025974 0.8235294 0.6335878 0.8382353 0.4852941 0.4285714 0.4705882          
9 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.7297297 1.0000000 0.4736842 0.6666667 0.3684211 0.7936508
```

What I would like to extract from my distance object is the distances between each plot between each time step like this :

```
Plot    distance1   distance 2  distance3
1   0.5 0.75    0.9
2   0.1 0.2 0.3
3   0.01    0.1 0.5
```

where distance1 would be the distance from time 1 to 2, distance2 would be the distance from time 2 to 3 and distance3 would be the distance from time 1 to time 3.

Is there a relatively easy way of extracting this info from a distance object?

Comment: You should describe a rule for going from either that `dist`-object (or perhaps from your data)  to your desired output. I don't see any of those numbers in that object. Problem description with words "kinda" and "like" are inherently unclear, and I suspect that desired output is not the exact answer you really wanted from that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to deal with this is probably to split the data by plot and then run `vegdist` on the three values for each plot.

```
require(plyr)
require(vegan)
ddply(example, .(plot), function(x)as.vector(vegdist(x[,-1])))
```

You probably should have a time column. You could use that to order the data to ensure that the first column of distances always represents the same times.